# set select list to current date using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, selectlist

I am using Jquery mobile, and I have these two select lists, I want to set the selected options for the to lists to the current day and month ..

edit I am using JqueryMobile

the code for 2 lists :

```
            <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
            <legend>تاريخ اخر دورة شهرية : </legend>
            <label for="select-choice-day">أختر الشهر</label>
            <select name="select-choice-day" id="select-choice-day">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="9">9</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
                <option value="11">11</option>
                <option value="12">12</option>
                <option value="13">13</option>
                <option value="14">14</option>
                <option value="15">15</option>
                <option value="16">16</option>
                <option value="17">17</option>
                <option value="18">18</option>
                <option value="19">19</option>
                <option value="20">20</option>
                <option value="21">21</option>
                <option value="22">22</option>
                <option value="23">23</option>
                <option value="24">24</option>
                <option value="25">25</option>
                <option value="26">26</option>
                <option value="27">27</option>
                <option value="28">28</option>
                <option value="29">29</option>
                <option value="30">30</option>
                <option value="31">31</option>
                <!-- etc. -->
            </select>


            <label for="select-choice-month">اختر الشهر</label>
            <select name="select-choice-month" id="select-choice-month">
                <option value="1">يناير</option>
                <option value="2">فبراير</option>
                <option value="3">مارس</option>
                <option value="4">إبريل</option>
                <option value="5">مايو</option>
                <option value="6">يونيو</option>
                <option value="7">يوليو</option>
                <option value="8">أغسطس</option>
                <option value="9">سبتمبر</option>
                <option value="10">أكتوبر</option>
                <option value="11">نوفمبر</option>
                <option value="12">ديسمبر</option>
                <!-- etc. -->
            </select>
            </fieldset>
```

The code for selecting the current day and month .. but it doesn't work !

```
var today = new Date();
        var day = today.getDate();
        var month = today.getMonth();
        alert(month);
        $('#select-choice-day option').get(day).attr('selected','selected');
        $('#select-choice-month option').get(month).attr('selected','selected');
```

Comment: In JavaScript month is 0 based... Jan = 0, Feb = 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that `.get()` on a jquery object returns the DOMElement at the index specified and not a jquery object anymore, so you cannot use .attr() on it ([source](http://api.jquery.com/get/)).

Here's a working piece of code:

```
$('#select-choice-day option[value=' + day + ']').prop('selected',true);
$('#select-choice-month option[value=' + (month+1)  + ']').prop('selected',true);
```

Please note that `.prop()` is only available for jquery 1.6 and above. If you are using an older version of the library, use `attr()` as you do.

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/hRu8f/)

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
var today = new Date();
$('#select-choice-day').val( today.getDate() );
$('#select-choice-month').val( today.getMonth() + 1 );
```

Remember to add `1` to `.getMonth()` since it is zero-indexed.

[Here is an example.](http://jsfiddle.net/owings1/nxqSB/)

Answer (score 1):

try this-

```
$('#select-choice-day option[value=' + day + ']').attr('selected',true);
$('#select-choice-month option[value=' + (month+1)  + ']').attr('selected',true);
```

[**Working Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/8nFx6/)