# Set select list to current date and next day with leading zeros

Tags: jquery

I've got a problem passing off date information to another site because they still require two digit dates even for the first nine days of the month. I've gotten 90% of the way using the code from the SO page for [set select list to current date using Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8164508/set-select-list-to-current-date-using-jquery). That moves the months and days from 1-31 and 1-12. I need the output to be from 01-31 and 01-12.

The current situation:

```
function ragequit() {
    var today = new Date();
    var daym = today.getDate();
    var monthm = today.getMonth();
    $('#StartMonth option[value=' + (monthm)  + ']').prop('selected',true);
    $('#StartDay option[value=' + (daym) + ']').prop('selected',true);
    $('#EndMonth option[value=' + (monthm+1)  + ']').prop('selected',true);
    $('#EndDay option[value=' + (daym+1)  + ']').prop('selected',true);
}
```

It is calling the month perfectly because this is December. Also had to add `m` to each of the values so that it doesn't compete with another tool that increments the date when the start date is changed.

Simply put, I have `12 7 2011` - I need `12 07 2011`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow; please take some time to read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). If someone's answer has answered your question, please don't forget to click on the check mark next to their [answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/171243).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a function to pad a string with leading zeros, like this:

```
function pad(num, size) {
    var s = num+"";
    while (s.length < size) s = "0" + s;
    return s;
}
```

Then you can use this to add leading zeros to your dates:

```
function ragequit() {
    var today = new Date();
    var daym = today.getDate();
    var monthm = today.getMonth();
    $('#StartMonth option[value=' + pad(monthm,2)  + ']').prop('selected',true);
    $('#StartDay option[value=' + pad(daym,2) + ']').prop('selected',true);
    $('#EndMonth option[value=' + pad(monthm+1,2)  + ']').prop('selected',true);
    $('#EndDay option[value=' + pad(daym+1,2)  + ']').prop('selected',true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in my javascript tools library, I have functions for left and right padding of a string that I got from somewhere and use them all the time.
With this...

`String.prototype.lPad = function (n,c) {var i; var a = this.split(''); for (i = 0; i < n - this.length; i++) {a.unshift (c)}; return a.join('')}`

String.prototype.rPad = function (n,c) {var i; var a = this.split(''); for (i = 0; i < n - this.length; i++) {a.push (c)}; return a.join('')}

You can now do something like `alert ('8'.lPad(6,'0'))`

Or in your case...
`var monthm = today.getMonth().lPad(2,'0');`  (might need conversion)